# SharePoint Secure store services with oracle & PHP site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, secure-store

I have SharePoint intranet, can I use Secure Store Service in SharePoint 2013 to keep user logged in when he/she navigate from my SharePoint intranet portal to any of the below systems?

1. Traditional Authentication which is default from Oracle E-Business Suite.
2. PHP intranet portal using encrypted username /password related to PHP security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure store is used in case if SharePoint want to connect to 3rd Party Applications. The basic example is in case while creating an External Content Type, you can store the credentials of the back-end system in Secure Store.

In your case you should look into authenticating the other applications from SharePoint. For this you should leverage using some custom code in the Master Page which authenticates the other system using their API/WebServices. Then store the cookie etc to make it work seamlessly.